# Jquery check if class exists in one of the multiple elements

Tags: jquery, class, input, exists

How to check if there is a class in one of the many `li` elements, if so call a function ?

There is multiple `<div class="selectbox"/>` within nested `<input type="hidden"/>` and `<ul />` list. What i need is to check if inside each `.selectbox ul` is one of many `li a` element with associated `.selected` class. If so, pass it's value into `<input type="hidden"/>` value attribute.

Here is a code:

```
<div id="selectbox1" class="selectbox">
    <input type="hidden" name="selectbox1" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" name="value01">Option 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="value02">Option 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="value03" class="selected">Option 03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="value04">Option 04</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="value05">Option 05</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you guys to all of you, i choosed with the lowest ms response time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('.selectbox').each(function(){
   var $selected = $('a.selected',$(this));
    if($selected.length){
         $('input',$(this)).val($selected.text()); 
    }
});
```

Live example (with hidden changed to text for demo purpose): http://jsfiddle.net/YL4AB/
Live example 2 (Showing multiple `.selectbox` div's): http://jsfiddle.net/YL4AB/1/

Comment: HOT. Perfect situation to use the context parameter within the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it by getting a set of all of the `input` elements under the "selectbox" `div` and then finding the selected `a` (if any). E.g.:

```
$(".selectbox > input").each(function() {
    this.value = $(this).closest(".selectbox").find("a.selected").first().attr("name") || "";
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ayahed), I made the hidden input a text input so you could see it. Click the button to fire the above code. (Clicking the links changes which one is selected, but doesn't update the input -- so you can see what happens when you click the button.) I also used CSS to highlight the selected one.

Comment: Thank you Crowder! If i ever could accept all of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="selectbox1"]').val($("#selectbox1 li > a.selected").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code, explaining what it does:

```
// Grab the selectbox elements
$('.selectbox').each(function() {
    // Loop through the LI elements which have Anchor elements with the '.selected' class
    $(this).find('li a.selected').each(function() {
        // Execute arbitrary function
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

It's pretty simple, and fits in with what most everyone else has said.  Hopefully the documentation will help out a bit.

Comment: No problem.  This could actually be one line, using the each() function.  But when you separate them, you can easily grab the ID of the current .selectbox that you're looping through.  Otherwise you have to do something like $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id') to get that value.  But just understanding what you're doing is important.  Then the smaller things and code efficiency will begin to become more important.